# H2 INIT equivalent for Derby

Tags: h2, derby

Just like in H2 we have INIT to run scripts when connection is made to H2, is there any equivalent for this in derby ? I searched the net but did not find anything concrete.

Note:
I am not using Spring or any other heavy framework.